# When and why would I set a variable for another class in a new class init as an argument?

Tags: python, class, arguments

```
class SchoolOfFish:
    def __init__(self, position, fish_class=Fish, number_of_fish=1):
        self.position = position
        self.timer = 0
        self.list_of_fish = []
        for i in range(number_of_fish):
            self.list_of_fish.append(fish_class(screen.size / 2))

class SchoolOfFish:
    def __init__(self, position, number_of_fish=1):
        self.position = position
        self.timer = 0
        self.list_of_fish = []
        for i in range(number_of_fish):
            self.list_of_fish.append(Fish(screen.size / 2))
```

Both of these do the same thing, which is to populate SchoolOfFish.list_of_fish with instances of a previous class "Fish". Is there an advantage to including the variable "fish_class" as in the first example? 
Also, I've been unable to find Python documentation concerning setting default values in class **init** methods as arguments. Could you point me to an explanation of how that works?

Comment: Do you change `fish_class` often enough to need to make it configurable? If not, then this just adds unnecessary complexity. What do you mean by *setting default values in class `__init__` methods as arguments*?

Comment: For this program, no the fish_class will not change, so it's unneeded complexity.
I may be using the wrong words here, but I'm curious about setting values of attributes of SchoolOfFish in the __init__ method arguments, such as def __init__(number_of_fish=1). What's the correct terminology to refer to that?

Comment: As for your second question, they're just called default argument values: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would allow you to use the `SchoolOfFish` class with different types other than just the hard-coded `Fish`.

In the top example, the default is `Fish`, but another class can be specified at runtime when the constructor is called.

**Edit re: default args:**

Regarding default args in `__init__`, it's not conceptually any different than setting a default value for arguments in any other method/function. Simply specify `x=y` where `x` is the argument name and `y` is its default value.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you can initialise a `SchoolOfFish` of different classes of fish.

Both the constructors provided provide a default, if `fish_class` isn't specified, then it defaults to constructing a list of generic `Fish`.

However, `fish_class` allows you to specify a certain class of fish.

For example, you might want to initialise a school of `Baracuda`, or school of `Snapper`, both of which would be subclasses of the generic `Fish` class.

(Actually there's nothing in the code that's making sure that `fish_class` is actually a `Fish` class, you could call the constructor with `fish_class = Dog`).